# delete another excel or word file without closing it through excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete a word/excel/ppt application opened through VBA without closing the application. This is the code I am trying to run now but it doesnot delete the file, rather goes to errorhandler.

```
Private Sub M111_Click()
Dim WDObj As Object
Dim WDApp As Object
Dim str As String

Set WDObj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tools").OLEObjects("VOC")
WDObj.Verb xlOpen

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set wordap = GetObject(, "word.Application")

str = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Voice of Customer.doc"
wordap.activedocument.SaveAs (str)
wordap.activedocument.Close

wordap.documents.Open str, ReadOnly = True

wordap.Activate

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
With wordap.activedocument
   Kill str
   End With
Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: you can't.  That's against the law of nature.

Comment: So you go to the error handler, did you look at the error? What are the Err Number and Description?

Comment: error number 70: permission denied. I run a code executing well to delete the activeworkbook while its till open. Why cann't we delete some other open file as well @cyboashu?

Comment: if the file is already open, just by windows logic you cannot delete it.. so don't think that's allowed.. On a separate note: if you are setting `On Error GoTo ErrorHandler`, don't forget to reset back to `On Error GoTo 0` at the end of your UDF

Answer (score 0):

Your solution in that case is to not send a command to close the workbook. Instead, you could set the "Saved" state of the workbook to true, which would circumvent any messages about closing an unsaved book. Note: this does not save the workbook; it just makes it look like it's saved.

ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
and then, right after

Application.Quit

Comment: application.quit does not delete the file. I applied the same code to activeworkbook and it seems to work but just not on the another file

Answer (score 0):

Copy the document you want to delete first, then close the original, then delete the original.
I assume this is what you want except the document you created doesn't have the correct name and you cannot change it's name without saving it to it's correct name.
You could to some degree make it look like it has the correct name with application.Caption and inserting a Application.DocumentBeforeSave and DocumentBeforeSave  sub into the word's document object. (How to do this is described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/0c3db3d4-5876-40f0-a88c-d4c0ba69e755/how-can-i-dynamically-define-subfunction-at-runtime-in-vba?forum=officegeneral)

A copied object will become active after copying, so
     set copied_document = wordap.activedocument
should help in safely adressing the newly created file during runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround!! I am taking this long path to create a local copy of embedded OLE object. this copy is saved to local and opened. I need to open the OLE object as read only and could not find any other way. After opening the copy of OLE object, I need to delete it locally because there are a lot of OLE objects to be opened and saving each one's copy could take a lot of space (basically user doesnot want/need the automatic saving of the OLE object, but I have to do it to prevent embedded OLE object from being edited).

Comment: Is your problem preventing the user from editing the file? Maybe it is easier to embed the object in a password protected excel-sheet then.